# QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded error in zorin os

Tags: qt, zorin, qtcreator

Recently I have installed Zorin os and qt creator from [enter link description here][1]

[1]: https://flathub.org. I need to connect the lamp server which I have installed.
I am using qt creator and here is my sample code to connect the MySQL database.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("csms");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("");
    bool ok = db.open();

    if(ok) {
        qDebug() << "Database connected." << Qt::endl;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Database connection error." << db.lastError ()<< Qt::endl;
    }
```

But failed. I am googling the last two days but no luck. Now I am here. I need help.

Comment: how does it fail?

Comment: it gives "QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded error"

Answer (score 0):

Use `qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers()` look which drivers you have.

If the QMYSQL is not on the list - compile it: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html

Comment: QMYSQL driver is missing how to compile/load this driver ?

Comment: I am new so please guide me. thanks